# URL Routing and QueryStrings in ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, url-routing

I am trying to implement URL Routing for a non MVC application. Here's my original URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/ProcessStuff.aspx?id=1029019
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com/Process-This-Stuff/1029019
```

I have difficulty when the page has query strings in the URL.

This is the route handler I have so far:

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("ProcessStuff.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "URL Rewriting Module for IIS" will solve your problem and save you a lot of time!

http://www.iis.net/expand/URLRewrite

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/